# C++ to Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly

I have this question that i have to convert only the nested loop to assembly (8086). Do you guys mind to teach me or show me the code? Thanks very much

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    time_t start, end;
    unsigned short a, b, c, y, count=0;
    float diff;

    cout << "Enter y : ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Calculation start..." << endl;
    start = clock();


    //Convert this nested for loop to assembly instructions
    **for (a=0; a<y; a++)
        for (b=0; b<y; b++)
            for (c=0; c<y; c++)
                if ((a + 2*b - 8*c) == y)
                    count++;**


    //Do not change the code below
    end = clock();
    diff = (float)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    cout << "Calculation complete." << endl;
    cout << "Time used is " << diff << " second" << endl;
    cout << "There are " << count << " combination to produce " << y << endl;

    system ("pause");
```

Comment: define "teach me". "give me the code" is definitely not an acceptable question, especially since you didn't show any effort.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Im try to learn but i dont really know how the code should go, umm you can just ignore the "give me the code" thingy. Sorry

Comment: I'd start by looking up a tutorial or maybe rereading the notes from the lessons.

Comment: This question from the "related" panel looks useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178/8086-assembler-tutorial?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

let's say we want to translate the following loop:

for(int x = 0; x < y; x++)

X86 Assembler does not directly support `for` loops, but `do..while` loops translate very well  to assembly. Thus, the first step is to translate the loop into do..while:

```
int x = 0;
do {
 ..
 x ++;
} while(x < y);
```

`do ... while(x)` can be rewritten as `block: ... if(!x) goto block`

I'll leave it up to the reader to assemble the instructions correctly, but the instructions are:

- `MOV dst, src` overwrites `src` with `dst`. Since you don't have enough registers to do three nested loops and a computation within, `src` will probably be a memory location. Remember you can't use more than one memory location in an X86 instruction.
- `INC dst` increments the value at `dst`. I  think that a memory location will work here just fine, but if not, flank with a pair of `MOV`s.
- `CMP arg, arg` performs arithmetic subtraction, sets the appropriate flags and discards the difference. This lets you know which of two (signed) arguments is bigger or smaller. Remember that both arguments cannot be memory locations.
- `JLE label` jumps to `label` if flags indicate that the first argument to `CMP` (if the last instruction that set the flags was `CMP` (or `SUB`)) was Less or Equal than the second one, assuming both arguments were signed.
- `JL, JGE, JG` work similarly, just with Less, Greater than or Equal, Greater
- `JA, JB, JAE, JBE` (Jump if Above / Below) work similarly, but assume the arguments were unsigned instead.
- labels are denoted with colons, like in C/C++
- if you feel the need for an unconditional jump, use `JMP`. You shouldn't need it for a `do..while` loop, but they come in handy if you want a `while` loop instead.

Ref. (A-M): http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf
Ref. (N-Z): http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can compile C/C++ code with a `-S` flag to generate the assembly code from your source. However if you just copy the code it will be extremely easy to tell. This in combination with `O0` can generate some helpful assembly to look at.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his teacher meant hand-conversion. I believe that the automated compile will be easily noticeable and useless as a homework

Comment: yes Jan Dvorak i need hand-conversion but I didnt meant to copy and paste the code. As i said i wanna learn it and understand it, not just simplay copy and paste as this is a past year final question. I dont wanna take risk.
Jason Salter, do i need to use push and pop method for this loop?

Comment: You won't NEED to use those specifically, but there is a lot to keep track of so you will need to store some information on the stack. Like with any program, there is a lot of ways to go about writing that code. You can also store and access information on the stack by storing things relative to the stack pointer.